# Instagram API - is it possible to get notified when a photo is liked?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Hi I have been looking through the Instagram API documentation and I can't figure out how to get notified when a particular photo has been liked. Is this even possible? Or do I need to constantly query the photos in question to return their current likes? I can see how to get notified of other things, such as when a photo has been tagged, but not when one has been liked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in the current API (v1). The real-time service just provides user/tag/location/geography subscriptions.

You need to query the media likes for the desired photo regularly.